# Change img tag using jquery from a list of items and an url stored in an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a list of items displaying a link in my view like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(cardPackInfo.mCard.mMasterCard.mCardName, "ViewItemDetails", "Item", null, new { @class = "cardImage", @data_id = cardPackInfo.mCard.mMasterCard.mCardImageLink})
```

As you can see, I'm trying to store a data in a kind of `@data_id` like I did.

I have a field dedicated to display an image:

```
<div id="image">
    <img id="cardImageDiv" src="~/Images/Functional/cardback.jpg" alt="defaultCard" class="nullify"/>
</div>
```

and my jQuery script is like this:

```
$('.cardImage').mouseover(function() {
    var imageSrc = $(this).attr("data-id");

    alert(imageSrc);
    $('#cardImageDiv').attr('src', imageSrc);

    var newImage = $('#cardImageDiv').attr('src');
    alert(newImage);
});
```

So what I'm trying to do is, when the user's mouse is over one of the link, I take the url when the image is located (which is stored in my model at `cardPackInfo.mCard.mMasterCard.mCardImageLink` and change the src of the current image located in the image src with the id `cardImageDiv`.

However the image is **not** changing. The two alerts are there to testify that the first data obtained is the url of the image (which may look like this: `~\Images\CardsImages\Return to Ravnica\(RTR) - 231 - NameOfTheCard.jpeg`) and the second alert tells me of the current src. But the result I have is that the first image is removed and I have the small "broken link" icon. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you manually browse to the url of that image? Is the image extension jpeg or jpg, I have had issues with images with jpeg extensions with some browsers!

Comment: Yep, I can manually browse to it and I can certify the image is there. It's even working with some custome html helpers that displays the image fine...

Comment: Can you try with the src like "/Images/etc" and lose the ~

Comment: Ah, ok. It's because I don't want to manually go to the directory since the directory of the app will change. So I used this symbol to tell the string it's a non-direct directory, don't remember the word for that.

Comment: Absolute reference VS relative reference.

Comment: You'll have to put your suggestion as answer, because that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the src like "/Images/etc" and lose the ~